# Behavior of specifying remote repositories as included in Artifactory backup

Tags: artifactory

There are remote repositories specified as to be "included" in my Artifactory backup.

What is the behavior of this: will only the cached artifacts be included, or will all remote artifacts be included.

I presume the former, but I cannot find the behavior described anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artifactory will only backup the cached artifacts.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I'll take your word for it, but is there some reference you can point to, for the sake of completely documenting this?

Comment: Sorry, no documented reference about this (besides the source code)